# Sorting a vector using values in another vector

Tags: c++

I have a `std::vector` called `foo_vec` containing objects of class `Foo`. Suppose that `Foo` has a member variable `int x`, and I also implemented a function `CompareInts(int a, int b)` which returns the minimum of `a` and `b`. Then, I could do an `std::sort` the vector in terms of the object's `x` values.

However, what if these `x` values are not member variables of `Foo`, but are in another `std::vector` called `x_vec`. Here, the first element of `x_vec` corresponds to the first element of `foo_vec`, and so on. How can I perform an `std::sort` on `foo_vec` based on the corresponding values in `x_vec`?

Comment: Is there a requirement that `x_vec`'s order be maintained?

Comment: No, it is fine if `x_vec` is reordered.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it lacks a minimal example.

Comment: This technique is known as "parallel arrays" and it's as old as FORTRAN, before the days is structs. As you've noticed, it can be awkward.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make a third vector of *indexes* and sort that indirectly. After it's sorted, you can access the original vector through the sorted indexes:

```
std::vector<Foo> foo_vec = /* ... */;
std::vector<int> x_vec = /* ... */;
std::vector<std::size_t> index_vec;

assert(foo_vec.size() == x_vec.size());
for (std::size_t i = 0; i != foo_vec.size(); ++i) { index_vec.push_back(i); }

std::sort(
    index_vec.begin(), index_vec.end(),
    [&](std::size_t a, std::size_t b) { return x_vec[a] < x_vec[b]; });

for (std::size_t i = 0; i != index_vec.size(); ++i)
{
    std::cout << "Sorted element " << i << " is "
              << foo_vec[index_vec[i]] << "\n";
}
```

Note that this operation is entirely non-invasive, since everything happens indirectly.

Comment: Here's a [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1267878/4859885) to a nice algorithm for reordering vectors based on indices

Comment: Foo class needs to overload the ´<<` operator I think

Comment: @Elyasin: Sure, that was just for demonstrating how to access the element.

Comment: It's allright. I reckoned it's basic for you. Just mentioned so others know. Excellent example I have to say. To me it shows a very good use case for lambda expression. Thumbs up.

Comment: @KerrekSB It seems the `index_vec` is not sorted using `x_vec` but using its own members. Wouldn't this just leave the `index_vec` unchanged?

Comment: @legends2k: Why does it seem that way? We are clearly passing iterators of `index_vec` to `sort`...?

Comment: @KerrekSB That's true, but the key to sort the elements, as per the question, should come from `x_vec.x`, where is that part in the above code? The comparator lambda uses `index_vec[a]`, not `x_vec[a]`, as the key; perhaps it's a typo.

Comment: @legends2k: Oh, sorry, that was a typo. The comparator should reference `x_vec`. Fixed (?).

Answer (score 2):

You create a third vector of int, which are the indexes into the original two vectors.  Initially populate the third vector with number 0 .. length of vector.  Then construct your compare function to take the index from the third vector and then do the compare against the second vector holding the keys.

The data in the first and second vector will not be modified (which is good) and the values in the the third vector will represent the sort order once done.