# Mapping a vector to specific range

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have a standard vector contains, for example, the following elements

`[-6, -7, 1, 2]`

I need to map these elements to the range from 1 to 4. i.e I need the vector to be like this

`[2, 1, 3, 4]`

Note that: the smallest value in the first vector (-7) was mapped to the smallest value in the second vector (1). How can I achieve that with STL?

Comment: Getting the range is easy (`1` to `my_vector.size()`). As for the positioning, it might be solved by just placing the values in the second vector from smallest to largest, and then sort it using the values from the first vector.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, creating a range and sorting it would be one option (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37369858/3182664 ). In fact, the specific case here can basically be considered as looking for a *sorting permutation* (or its inverse).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a helper vector of pairs:

```
std::vector<int> a { -6, -7, 1, 2 };

std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> tmp;
for (int i = 0; i < (int) a.size(); ++i) {
    tmp.push_back({ a[i], i });
}

std::sort(tmp.begin(), tmp.end());

std::vector<int> b;
for (auto & x : tmp) {
    b.push_back(x.second + 1);
}
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/25b2a01defe0fc2e)

---

Using a helper priority_queue of pairs (to avoid explicit sorting):

```
std::vector<int> a { -6, -7, 1, 2 };

std::priority_queue<std::pair<int, int>> tmp;
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i) {
    tmp.push({ -a[i], i});
}

std::vector<int> b;
do {
    b.push_back(tmp.top().second + 1);
} while (tmp.pop(), !tmp.empty());
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4747435342165ae1)

Answer (score 5):

With [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3):

```
std::vector<int> v{-6, -7, 1, 2};
auto res = ranges::view::ints(1, 1 + (int)v.size()) | ranges::to_vector;

ranges::sort(ranges::view::zip(v, res));
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/726a1e44d8023040)

Comment: thanks but I needed a standard solution, but I will remember to use this great library.

Answer (score 5):

With just the standard library as it exists in C++17 (or really, C++11), you make a vector of indices and sort it - using itself as a projection:

```
vector<int> idxs(values.size());
iota(idxs.begin(), idxs.end(), 1);
sort(idxs.begin(), idxs.end(), [&](int i, int j){
    return values[i-1] < values[j-1];
});
```

A different way of generating the indices would be to use `generate_n`:

```
vector<int> idxs;
generate_n(back_inserter(idxs),
    values.size(),
    [cnt=1]() mutable { return cnt++; });
// same sort()
```