# When passing a function as an argument to another, what does it mean to put "[]" before it?

Tags: c++, sorting

I was checking an answer to a question posted on stackoverflow:

[Answer to: C++, Sort One Vector Based On Another One](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37368873)

The answer has this piece of code:

```
std::sort(people.begin(), people.end(), 
               [](const auto& i, const auto& j) { return i.Score < j.Score; } );
```

I just want to understand why "[]" is put before the function here.

Thanks!

Comment: This is really a lambda, which is not exactly like a function. And `[]` Is used for captures; Lambdas can "capture" outside variables/references to outside variables and use them in the function definition. It's optional though, and in this case, the answerer chose to leave out captures because they weren't needed.

Comment: `[](){}` part is basically an anonymous function.

Comment: imho it is amazing that `[](){}();` is now valid c++ syntax, especially if you consider how much code was necessary to achieve the same without a lambda expression