# sorting two vectors using c++ with condition

Tags: c++, c++11

I have two vectors vector a and vector b and I want to sort them both with the condition that a[i]/b[i]>a[i+1]/b[b+1]. How do I implement the code in C++ for that?

Comment: Can you share the program which you made to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Say you start with

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> a{2, 7, 3};
    std::vector<int> b{4, 2, 1};
```

Create a vector of indices, `inds`:

```
    std::vector<std::size_t> inds;
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i)
        inds.push_back(i);
```

also create a comparison function describing the criteria in your question:

```
    auto cmp = [&](std::size_t lhs, std::size_t rhs) {
        return static_cast<double>(a[lhs]) / b[lhs] > static_cast<double>(a[rhs]) / b[rhs];
    };
```

and sort according to it:

```
    std::sort(std::begin(inds), std::end(inds), cmp);
}
```

At this point, `inds` will be organized according to your criteria.

Finally, use the answers in [reorder a vector using a vector of indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838384/reorder-vector-using-a-vector-of-indices) to reorder each of `a` and `b` according to `inds`.